# How do I stop a single word from hyphenating

Tags: hyphenation

Can I force a word to jump to the next line ?

This is my code; I use special hyphenation rules for albanian :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{albanian}

\hyphenation{ko-sta-n-di-no-po-jës} %<- for this example

\begin{document}

\textbf{{\large Burimet kryesore për historinë e rënies së Kostandinopojës}}

\end{document}
```

and the result is this :
[image]

I would like the word Kostandinopojës to jump to the next line. `\mbox{Kostandinopojës}` didnt do the trick

Comment: By "`\mbox{Kostandinopojës}` didn't do the trick" you mean that it stopped hyphenation, but didn't put the word on the line below it?

Comment: Yes, the word simply continued beyond the margins, quite ugly. Maybe there is a solution in that direction.

Comment: You need to add also (beside using a box) some more stretch to the  wordspace, e.g. with \sloppy or not so drastic with `\emergencystretch 1ex`.

Comment: @alfred: You can also issue `\linebreak` just before that word...

Comment: in connection with @UlrikeFischer's suggestion regarding `\sloppy`, using instead the environment `sloppypar` around that paragraph would restrict the effect to just the one paragraph.

Comment: I thought I already was using  ´\sloppy´ but I wasnt and it worked, also ´\linebreak´ didnt add any space so it also worked fine. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: unrelated to the hyphenation but you should never do `{\large Burimet kryesore për historinë e rënies së Kostandinopojës}` that sets large text on a normal baseline so the text will not fit and you will get inconsistent vertical spacing of the lines. Alway send the paragraph in the scope of the size change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Should i use `\begin{large}..` or end with `\par`

Comment: `\begin{large} zzz\end{large}` is the same as `{\large zzz}` either way you want the paragraph to end before the end of the size change, it's more usual to use a blank line, but `\par` is the same thing.